# Xamarin background, не запускается приложение

Tags: android, c#, xamarin

Выводит мне вот такое, что делать?
Transparent стоит у меня на Imagebutton

```
<ImageButton android:src="@drawable/next"
             android:layout_width="49.0dp"
             android:layout_height="50.8dp"
             android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
             android:layout_marginLeft="0.0dp"
             android:background="transparent" />
```

Ошибка

> string types not allowed (at 'background' with value 'transparent')

Comment: Может быть, покажете конкретный код?

Comment: Уже решил проблемы, заменой 'Transparent ' на #00000000

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
android:background="#00000000"
```

или так:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```